# Ideas on how to create kinematic model of skid-steered rocker bogie mobile robot

Tags: mobile-robot, kinematics, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics, robot-model

I'm trying to derive the inverse kinematics of a skid-steered mobile robot with rocker-bogie mechanism.

I learned how to derive the kinematics via transformation matrices as per "[Kinematic modeling of wheeled mobile robots](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/muir_patrick_1986_1/muir_patrick_1986_1.pdf)" by Muir and Neumann.

I also read several papers ([link1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/772441), [link2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4210530_A_general_approach_to_kinematics_modeling_of_all-terrain_rovers), [link3](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220797306_Traction_Control_for_a_Rocker-Bogie_Robot_with_Wheel-Ground_Contact_Angle_Estimation), [link4](https://www.seekdl.org/conferences/paper/details/5232.html)) doing the kinematic modeling of rocker-bogie robots, but all of them has active steering, so they don't need the differential drive equations.

But the problem with the method in "Kinematic modeling of wheeled mobile robots" is that it does not capture the ICC (instantaneous center of curvature) method for differential drive (or skid-steering for more than 2 drive wheels).

In deriving the forward kinematics (as per Muir and Neumann), you will get robot velocities in terms of joint variables (including wheel rotational velocities), which can will lead to deriving the robot's Jacobian WRT wheel contact frame.

But I have no idea on how to somehow plug in the differential drive equations in there.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Haven't thought much about this, but a couple of knee-jerk thoughts: First, wouldn't forward speed be the *average* of left and right sides, and rotation rate be the *difference* between left and right sides over the distance between the left and right sides? Second, probably all bets are off when you allow for wheel slip. I'd be interested to see what equations you've got with an explanation of what difficulty you're having with merging them.